# Map Document Reference In Object with SnapshotChanges in AngularFire

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angularfire

I have a class that looks like the following:

```js
export class Business {
  name: string;
  docRef: DocumentReference;

  constructor(name: string, docRef: DocumentReference) {
    this.name = name;
    this.docRef = docRef;
  }
}
```

What I would like is to able to easily manipulate this object in Firestore to store the `DocumentReference` when getting the data. For example currently I have the following:

```
this.firestore.collection<Business>('businesses').doc<Business>(id).valueChanges();
```

... but I know I need to use [`snapshotChanges`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#snapshotchanges) to get the metadata (i.e. the DocumentReference).

How can I easily map the `DocumentReference` into my `Business` object when I retrieve it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simpler than I was expecting so I decided to come back here and post the answer to see if it helps anyone.

Given the example of `Business` add the following method to `Business`:

```
static fromFirestore(doc: DocumentSnapshot<Business>): Business {
  return ({
    name: doc.data().name,
    docRef: doc.ref,
  });
}
```

then when reading it call the following:

```
this.firestore.collection<Business>('businesses').doc<Business>(id).snapshotChanges().subscribe((value) => {
      this.business = Business.fromFirestore(value.payload);
    });
```

Or if you want to instead return an observable string do the following:

```
return this.firestore.collection<Business>('businesses').doc<Business>(id).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(value => Business.fromFirestore(value.payload))
    );
```

Hope this helps someone.